# How to set a value on rsuitejs selectpicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rsuite

```
const _DATA = [{
  code: 'code1',
  name: 'Jagger'
},{
  code: 'code2',
  name: 'Tigger'
},{
  code: 'code3',
  name: 'Lion'
}]

 <SelectPicker
      data={_DATA.map(x => {return {label: x.name, value: x.code} })}
      style={{ width: 224 }}
      defaultValue={_DATA[1].label}
    />
```

How do I set the value of `code1` for example I have a form then it will set the `code1` when opening the form/drawer. cause I have a list then I have edit button. when I try to select the data which is the `code1` then it should automatically display. but on my side it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to map data. SelectPicker support pass valueKey and labelKey.
And you can pass code value to SelectPicker.

```
const _DATA = [{
  code: 'code1',
  name: 'Jagger'
},{
  code: 'code2',
  name: 'Tigger'
},{
  code: 'code3',
  name: 'Lion'
}]

 <SelectPicker
      data={_DATA}
      valueKey="code"
      labelKey="name"
      style={{ width: 224 }}
      defaultValue={_DATA[0].code}
    />
```

Comment: I tried like this but it doesn't work also ```defaultValue={![null,undefined].includes(control.getValues()['code'])  ? control.getValues()['building']['name'] : control.getValues()['code']}```

Comment: yes, but when I try to console the _DATA[0] it work. but when I try to console with ['code'] its undefined

Comment: what is control.getValues()?

Comment: ```const { control, register, errors } = useFormContext();```

Comment: may be you can provider the complete code on codesanbox.

Comment: According to the code you provided, it is difficult to find the reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230431/discussion-between-superman66-and-beginner-coder).